# Caused by: org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: sftp:

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

I am trying to sftp a file from my server to a remote mailbox using apache camel.
I generated ssh keys for the user and associated the public key to the mailbox on remotehost. I am using the private key to connect to the mailbox folder. When I used the sftp client like CyberDuck I am able to connect to the mailbox and transfer the files.

```
@Override
    public void configure() throws Exception{
    from("file:/myfolder/")
            .to("sftp://remote_host//mailbox_folder?username=username&" +
                    "privateKeyFile=private_key_file")
            .log(LoggingLevel.INFO,"file transferred successfully")
            .end();
}
```

I have the following dependencies in the project:

```
compile group: 'org.apache.camel', name: 'camel-spring-boot-starter', version: "2.20.1"
compile group: 'org.apache.camel', name: 'camel-quartz', version: "2.20.1"
compile group: 'org.apache.camel', name: 'camel-ftp-starter', version: "2.20.1"
compile group: 'com.jcraft', name: 'jsch', version: '0.1.55'
compile group: 'org.apache.camel', name: 'camel-ftp', version: "2.20.1"
```

I am getting the following error:

```
2020-07-29 14:04:38.004  | ERROR  | SpringApplication | Application startup failed
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route1 at: >>> To[sftp://remote_host//mailbox_folder?username=username&privateKeyFile=private_key_file] <<< in route: Route(route1)[[From[file:/my_folder/]] -> [O... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: sftp://remote_host//mailbox_folder?privateKeyFile=private_key_file&username=username due to: No component found with scheme: sftp
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapRuntimeCamelException(ObjectHelper.java:1831) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.start(SpringCamelContext.java:136) ~[camel-spring-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.onApplicationEvent(SpringCamelContext.java:174) ~[camel-spring-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:393) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:347) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:883) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at com.example.apache-sftp.main(DataPublisher.java:24) [main/:?]
Caused by: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route1 at: >>> To[sftp://remote_host//mailbox_folder?username=username&privateKeyFile=private_key_file] <<< in route: Route(route1)[[From[file:/my_folder/]] -> [O... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: sftp://remote_host//mailbox_folder?privateKeyFile=private_key_file&username=username due to: No component found with scheme: sftp
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:1298) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:204) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRoute(DefaultCamelContext.java:1148) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:3727) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:3441) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.access$000(DefaultCamelContext.java:208) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:3249) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:3245) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWithDefinedClassLoader(DefaultCamelContext.java:3268) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:3245) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:3168) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.start(SpringCamelContext.java:133) ~[camel-spring-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    ... 16 more
Caused by: org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: sftp://remote_host//mailbox_folder?privateKeyFile=private_key_file&username=username due to: No component found with scheme: sftp
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:769) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.util.CamelContextHelper.getMandatoryEndpoint(CamelContextHelper.java:80) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.resolveEndpoint(RouteDefinition.java:219) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.resolveEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:115) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.resolveEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:121) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.model.SendDefinition.resolveEndpoint(SendDefinition.java:62) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.model.SendDefinition.createProcessor(SendDefinition.java:56) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.makeProcessorImpl(ProcessorDefinition.java:549) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.makeProcessor(ProcessorDefinition.java:510) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.addRoutes(ProcessorDefinition.java:226) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:1295) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:204) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRoute(DefaultCamelContext.java:1148) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:3727) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:3441) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.access$000(DefaultCamelContext.java:208) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:3249) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:3245) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWithDefinedClassLoader(DefaultCamelContext.java:3268) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:3245) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:3168) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.start(SpringCamelContext.java:133) ~[camel-spring-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
    ... 16 more
2020-07-29 14:04:38.004  | INFO   | AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext | Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@3c947bc5: startup date [Wed Jul 29 14:04:33 CDT 2020]; root of context hierarchy
```

What is that I am missing here?

Comment: Can you do an `mvn clean install`

Comment: Since this app is a gradle app I did `./gradlew clean build` and still same issue. Also there was another app which is actually performing FTP pull from external servers using Apache Camel. I did try from that app and the above piece of code is still giving me the same error

Comment: Sorry! That's what I meant. Mvn has become ingrained after using it so much. Can you remove the `camel-ftp` dependency and check? You already have the `camel-ftp-starter` dependency.

Answer (score 0):

The problem got resolved when I did multiple clean build (using gradle) and for some weird reason worked after restarting my machine